# How can I separate a column within a Pandas dataframe into unique bins / columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a current dataframe with the structure:

```
customer    item 1  item 2  item 3
John        Apples  Oranges Bananas
Blake       Bananas
Steph       Oranges Bananas
```

I'm interested in parsing each column and placing them into unique columns associated with the same name; i.e.:

```
customer    item 1  item 2  item 3
John        Apples  Oranges Bananas
Blake                       Bananas
Steph               Oranges Bananas
```

What would be the optimal way of doing this within Pandas / Numpy?

Comment: Are those empty spots actual empty strings or `NaN`?

Comment: Empty Strings ('None')

Comment: Do you truly need that output? With that organization it's far more natural to work with dummies (column name is the unique item and a 1/0 indicates participation in that category)

Comment: that would work as well, I'm just looking to sum/count the totals of unique columns with a groupby function

Comment: what do you mean by "unique columns" are you just wanting a count of items in the data for each customer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution that will give you your desired result.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'customer':['John','Blake','Steph'],'item1':['Apples','Bananas','Oranges'],'item2':['Oranges',np.nan,'Bananas'],'item3':['Bananas',np.nan,np.nan]})
#Get unique items
df=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['customer'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(pd.pivot_table(df,columns='value',index='customer',aggfunc='count').to_records())
df2.columns=['customer','item1','item2','item3']
df2['item1'][df2['item1']==1]='Apples'
df2['item2'][df2['item2']==1]='Bananas'
df2['item3'][df2['item3']==1]='Oranges'
df2
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to reshape the data into the columns in the original post I think it would be best to reshaped the data into what's called a [tidy form](https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html) where every row equals one observation and then applying the group by. Especially if the end results is a count or sum of the items/customers in question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['john', 'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'], ['blake', 'bananas', '', ''],
                              ['steph', '', 'bananas', 'bananas']]),
                    columns=['customer', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3'])

# make tidy
tidy_data = pd.melt(data, ['customer'], var_name=['cols'], value_name='item')
tidy_data = tidy_data[['customer', 'item']]
#count each type of item the customer has 
grouped_data = tidy_data.groupby(['customer', 'item'])['item'].count().rename(columns={'item': 'counts'})
grouped_data = grouped_data.reset_index(name='counts')
grouped_data = grouped_data[grouped_data.item != '']
grouped_data
```

which gives this output:

```
  customer     item  counts
1    blake  bananas       1
2     john   apples       1
3     john  bananas       1
4     john  oranges       1
6    steph  bananas       2
```

if you just need the counts of each item and not the customer then just do this for the group by

```
grouped_data = tidy_data.groupby(['item'])['item'].count().rename(columns={'item': 'counts'})
grouped_data = grouped_data.reset_index(name='counts')
```

which gives this output:

```
      item  counts
1   apples       1
2  bananas       4
3  oranges       1
```